# What is the best site/youtube to learning lighting for photography?

Tags: lighting

I am using canon 7D and I am learning lighting. Does anyone know good youtube account or site to learn lighting for photography? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Emma. "Best site" questions tend to get poor results — you'll get some favorite suggestions, a few of which will be good and others of which will be spam, and then the question will sit here for years attracting more spam and not many more good answers. But, check out the list of [tag:lighting-basics] questions on _this_ site — there's a lot to get you started, and you can ask questions about specific things you're interested in trying and I can almost guarantee great, helpful answers.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the first link will be to Strobist, and then every few months someone else will come along and suggest that. :)

Answer (score 3):

[strobist.blogspot.com](http://strobist.blogspot.com)

Start with [Lighting 101](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/03/lighting-101.html)

Comment: What about natural lighting?

Comment: @MichaelClark all of the same principles apply!

Comment: How do I attach a snoot to the sun? :-)

Comment: @MichaelClark you don't attach it directly to the sun, that would be hard. Instead you attach it to a window in an opaque wall approximately 149,600,000,000 meters *in front* of the sun.